# How to prevent an array of unit length in POST body from being converted to a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-requests

In node.js, I'm using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4310087/3664835) to extract POST data.

that is:

```
var qs = require('querystring');
function (request, response) {
    if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
            request.connection.destroy();
        });

        request.on('end', function () {
            var post = qs.parse(body);
            console.log(post.foo);
        });
    }
}
```

I am making requests using the Python requests library. When the array `foo` has more than one element the output is as expected.

`requests.post(url, data={'foo': ['bar', 'baz']})` gives `['bar', 'baz']`

However if the array has only one element in it the variable `foo` becomes a string!

`requests.post(url, data={'foo': ['bar']})` gives `bar` and not `['bar']`.

I would like to not do something like:

```
if (typeof post.foo === 'string')
    post.foo = [post.foo]
```

to ensure that the client sends only arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string format has no concept of "arrays".

The library you are using will just, when given an array of data, insert duplicate keys into the result. This is a standard practise.

So:

```
requests.post(url, data={'foo': 'one-value-only', 'bar': ['first-value', 'second-value']})
```

will give you:

```
foo=one-value-only&bar=first-value&bar=second-value
```

Then you parse that in JavaScript. You can see [the source code from the library you are using](https://github.com/Gozala/querystring/blob/master/decode.js). If it gets a second key with a given name, it replaces the value it returns with an array.

Nothing in that code gives you an option to always return an array.

That leaves you with three options:

1. Perform the test on the results that you say you don't want to perform
2. Edit the querystring library so that line 71 reads `obj[k] = [v];`
3. Use a different library